# Storing filename in db from ajax upload not working

Tags: php, ajax

When I use $filename below I can never store anything in the database. I've tried basename function but it doesn't seem to store anything.

```
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

        /* Location */
        $location = "../media/images/profile-pics/".$filename;
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($location,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        /* Valid Extensions */
        $valid_extensions = array("jpg","jpeg","png");
        /* Check file extension */
        if( !in_array(strtolower($imageFileType),$valid_extensions) ) {
           $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        if($uploadOk == 0){
           echo 0;
        }else{
           /* Upload file */
           if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$location)){


           }else{
              echo 0;
           }
        }

        //$filename = basename($_FILES['file']); removed, but still doesn't store file in db.


        $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE contacts SET name = ?, email = ?, phone = ?, jobtitle = ?, profile_pic = ? WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssi", $name, $email, $phone, $jobtitle, $filename, $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of `$filename = basename($_FILES['file']);` - you've already populated `$filename` with `$_FILES['file']['name']` up above, which is the correct way to access the filename of the file as it was uploaded.

Comment: Yeah I have removed it and it still doesn't store it.

Comment: Is it saving the file in the `media/images/profile-pics/` directory with the right filename?  Are other fields, `name`, `email`, etc. getting updated with the DB query?  Have you attempted to echo out what the `$filename` variable is holding at various points in the script?